# How to list recent places items without explore then

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

On windows 7, I need to click to "Recent places" to see it.

How to see all folders at the same level of desktop or download (right column of explorer) ?

The aim is to delete the step of the click, because I open only 3 folders a day, and their aren't on my local drive.

[image: http://images.pcastuces.com/adj/3656-2.png]

Imagine that "Fonds d'ecrans" are in the "Recent places" and I want to be at same level of Desktop

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Right-click your folder, and click **Copy**.
- Go to Recent Places.
- Right-click in empty space, and click **Paste shortcut**.

Answer (score 2):

- Open "Recent Places"
- Open one the of the folders you regularly go into.
- Once the folder is open in Explorer, right-click the "Favorites" entry, and choose "Add current location to Favorites".
- Repeat for other wanted folders.

[image]

Once you do this, they will appear under Favorites, at the same level as other Favorites like "Recent Places", and "Desktop".